# How to modify an XML file using Perl where in the XML file there is no start and end tag for certain nodes

Tags: perl

For Example the XML file is like

```
<ROOT> 
  <TESTING DUMMY="FALSE" NAME="SYSTEM"/> 
  <TESTING DUMMY="FALSE" NAME="SYSTEM1"> 
    <INSTANCE> 
      <PHY FREQ="1000"/> 
    </INSTANCE> 
  </TESTING> 
</ROOT>
```

Here in the XML file I want to update the FREQ value and save the file in different name. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *“no start and end tag for certain nodes”*?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
set /ROOT/TESTING[INSTANCE]/INSTANCE/PHY/@FREQ 42 ;
save :f newname.xml ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example - your `FREQ` tag *does* have a start and end. That's what the trailing `/` means. This is one of the reasons why parsing XML with a parser is important. It's a unary tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented' ) -> parsefile ( 'my.xml' );
$twig -> get_xpath('TESTING/INSTANCE/PHY',0) -> set_att('FREQ', 300);
$twig -> print;
```

(For printing to a file, you probably want `open` and `$twig -> sprint`);